# What radius should you take while converting rpm to m/s?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, unit-conversion

When converting rpm of, say a helicopter blade, to m/s, the equation used is:$$v_{m/s} = \frac{2\pi{r}}{60}\times N_{rpm} $$ In the equation, we have radius as a variable, as the speed changes with change in radius. Assume that the rpm of the **motor** that the blade is attached to is $250$ rpm, and the span of the blade is $1m$. I have read on some websites that you should not substitute the radius with the *whole* span of the blade, you should instead use half of the span of the blade as the radius, while on some other websites I have read that you should use $0.7$ of the span of the blade as the radius. I am right now confused about what fraction of the span to take as the radius, therefore it would be really helpful if anyone could tell me what the correct answer is. Thank you in advance. *Note: I'm using this value for the Lift equation, and as the velocity value of the blade is required in $m/s$ but I have the motor speed in rpm, a conversion is required*

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what you are using the data for.

The linear speed depends linearly of the distance from the centre.

Half the maximum speed (at the tip) gives the average speed.

$0.7(07) , \,\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ of the maximum speed is the root mean square speed, ie the square root of the average value of the speed squared, which you might use in kinetic energy, $\frac 12 mv^2$ calculations.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use the speed for the Lift equation, you have to compute the integral over the local lift from r=0 to r=max.

Maybe you can assume the blade profile to be the same all over the blade length, but real-world designs often have varying profile from center to the tips.